# Build issue in maven project on adding jasper-report dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

In my Spring based Camel maven project on adding the following dependency for Jasper reports , I am facing issue while project build.

Jasper Dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.4</version>
   </dependency>
```

Below is the stack trace for the exception:

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> RestBinding <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[rest:post:/request:/addMultiple?inType=j... because of Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1556)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:332)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> RestBinding <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[rest:post:/request:/addMultiple?inType=j... because of Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1028)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:841)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2895)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2618)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2467)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2486)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2432)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:255)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringInjector.newInstance(SpringInjector.java:39)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultDataFormatResolver.resolveDataFormat(DefaultDataFormatResolver.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolveDataFormat(DefaultCamelContext.java:3561)
    at org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingDefinition.createProcessor(RestBindingDefinition.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:505)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:217)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1025)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:458)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:379)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.<init>(JacksonDataFormat.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.<init>(JacksonDataFormat.java:96)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.<init>(JacksonDataFormat.java:84)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.<init>(JacksonDataFormat.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 46 more
```

I think the supporting jackson dependencies for the jasper reports are conflicting with previous dependencies.

Below is the Dependency Hierarchy of pom.xml for jasper report.

[image]

However if i remove the dependency for the jasper report then it is working fine.

I am not able to sort it out exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got your problem wrong, changed answer**

The class on which your method is occuring is part of jackson.core 2.4.3. If you include that explicitly, it should solve your problem.

Add the following dependencies:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId> 
    <version>2.4.3</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId> 
    <version>2.4.3</version> 
</dependency>
```